# Problem with WSUS database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, wsus

On server which I'm using for WSUS 3, one day i found this:

> The WSUS administration console was unable to connect to the WSUS Server Database.

Verify that SQL server is running on the WSUS Server. If the problem persists, try restarting SQL.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException -- Cannot open database "SUSDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

Source
.Net SqlClient Data Provider

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.SoapExceptionProcessor.DeserializeAndT
hrow(SoapException soapException)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DatabaseAccess.AdminDataAccessProxy.ExecuteSPG
etTargetGroupById(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.ComputerTargetGroup.GetById(Guid id, UpdateServer updateServer)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.UpdateServer.GetComputerTargetGroup(Guid id)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.AdminApiAccess.AdminApiTools.TestSqlConnection(IUpdateServer server)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.AdminApiAccess.AdminApiTools.GetUpdateServer(String serverName, Boolean useSecureConnection, Int32 portNumber)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Scope.ServerSummaryScopeNode.GetUpdateServer(PersistedServerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Scope.ServerSummaryScopeNode.ConnectToServer()
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Scope.ServerSummaryScopeNode.get_ServerTools()

I have no idea what the problem might be, 'cause my knowledge about DB's are minimal.

OS is Windows 2003 Server SP2, and nothing was changed or touched in server or system itself. Just one day, it didn't work anymore. Database is Microsoft SQL 2005

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log onto the WSUS server, and find the folder that SQL is installed in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\ by default.  Under that find the Log folder (should be under .\MSSQL\Log) and find the ERRORLOG file with no extension.  That should give you a better idea as to what's going on, if there's a database problem to deal with.

Failing that you may need to install the SQL Express Management Studio on the machine and connect to the database to see what's going on / correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the SQL Server instance is running?  Start SQL Server Configuration Manager from the Start Menu, and check out the services node.

Alternatively, you may be experiencing [this issue](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;956572) - I don't know enough about the sharepoint console to say for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

I love those Microsoft messages: "Try starting SQL Server". What they do not tell you is that there is no way to start SQL server that is immediately obvious to someone who has not done it before.

The advice above does not help anyone who's SQL server is not already running. How are you going to connect to an SQL server using anything if it is not running.

What is happening here is that the SQL server that came with WSUS has NO METHOD to check it or restart it. What is needed is to know how, via command line or whatever, to start the SQL server up again without having to restart the server node itself.